# NSString length restriction

Tags: iphone

Do we have any NSString length restriction when creating an object of NSURL class?

Answer (score 2):

There is no restriction that's part of the API. But if you create a ridiculously long URL, there is no guarantee that it will work in all situations (say, some servers might just say no). It's generally considered a good idea to avoid the need for exceedingly long URLs.